# Finding out the source of a git repository

Tags: linux, git

This might sound a weird question, But I want to know how can I find what was the source of some git repository that I have on my system.

In fact I have many Linux distributions from various git sources for cross compilation  and I have one distribution with quite unclear name that i had cloned some time back. Now i want to know the source of this git repository from which I got this project. How can I do that? Is there a git command for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it this way, querying git configs:

```
git config --get remote.origin.url
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do the following:

Update list of branches:

```
$ git remote update
```

Get overview of all branches + show which local branch is following the remotes:

```
$ git remote show origin
$ git branch -vv
```

Comment: Good to read it was useful, @UmairR. Remember you can accept an answer if your question is already solved.

Comment: +1 for one solution, accepting the other answer as it is Precise.